# Is it possible to simulate network latency on a physical rooted android device?

Tags: android, networking, latency

I'm trying to test the networking layer in our app, and have been wondering
if there is any way to simulate network latency on a rooted physical device.

I know it's possible on an emulator, but I'm required to do this on a physical device.

I know we can configure a router to simulate latency, but is there a tool that can be used
locally on the device for that purpose?

Thanks